# Ionic 3 how to receive an array from one page to another page

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular4-router

I need to pass an array from one page to another. In the first page the array is created by selecting items from a list and it push all itemes ok, but when I received this array in another page, it became an array object, and I cannot read the data in my html page, heres is part of my code :

labo.ts - this is the way I create my array, and its fine

```
selectItem(itemKey){
   const foundAt = this.selectedQuestions.indexOf(itemKey);
   if (foundAt >= 0) {
      this.selectedQuestions.splice(foundAt, 1);
   } else {
      this.selectedQuestions.push(itemKey);
   }
  console.log(this.selectedQuestions);
```

}

When I finish adding items, I send it to calendar.ts

```
calendar(){
 console.log("ARRAY ", this.selectedQuestions)
    this.navCtrl.push(CalendarioPage,{
      queryParams: {
           value : this.selectedQuestions
       },
  });
```

}

This is calendaar.ts, where I need to receive the array:

```
 export class CalendarioPage {
  datos: Array<object>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public http: Http, private conteSearch : ContesearchProvider) {

    this.datos = navParams.get("queryParams");

    console.log("array -> ", this.datos)

  }  
 }
```

In my calendar.html file I try to read the array :

```
<div *ngFor="let dato of datos">
  {{dato.nombre}} 
</div>
```

And I r eceived this error "ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

This is what it looks the array before and after (when received in calendar.ts)

[image]

Thank you in advance for any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passed array is available at value key of the object this.datos

So you need to read it like this.datos.value, that should work.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Tek, it works, thank you very much. I just change the html : <div *ngFor="let dato of datos.value">
      {{dato.nombre}} 
    </div>